# Fastest way to lookup bytes from 64-byte arrays

Tags: c++, performance

I have the following critical place in the code: I need to look up from 64-byte array around 1'000'000 times.

Minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#define TYPE uint8_t
#define n_lookup 64

int main(){
    const int n_indices = 1000000;
    TYPE lookup[n_lookup];
    TYPE indices[n_indices];
    TYPE result[n_indices];

    // preparations
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n_lookup);
    for (int i=0; i < n_indices; i++) indices[i] = distribution(generator);
    for (int i=0; i < n_lookup; i++) lookup[i] = distribution(generator);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // main loop:
    for (int i=0; i < n_indices; i++) {
        result[i] = lookup[indices[i]];
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "computation took " << elapsed_seconds.count() * 1e9 / n_indices  <<  " ns per element"<< std::endl;
    // printing random numbers to avoid code elimination
    std::cout << result[12] << result[45]; 
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with  `g++ lookup.cpp  -std=gnu++11 -O3 -funroll-loops` I get a bit less than 1ns per element on modern CPU.

I need this operation to work 2-3 times faster (without threads). How can I do this?

P.S. I also was investigating AVX512 (512 bits is exactly the size of lookup table!) instruction set, but it lacks 8-bit gather operations!

Comment: Could you cache the result?

Comment: @Galik, no, it doesn't make any sense for the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

`indices` and `result` vectors are in different places in memory, but accessed in the same time. It leads to cache-misses. I suggest you to merge result and indices in one vector. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#define TYPE uint8_t
#define n_lookup 64

int main(){
    const int n_indices = 2000000;
    TYPE lookup[n_lookup];
    // Merge indices and result
    // If i is index, then i+1 is result
    TYPE ind_res[n_indices];

    // preparations
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n_lookup);
    for (int i=0; i < n_indices; i += 2) ind_res[i] = distribution(generator);
    for (int i=0; i < n_lookup; i++) lookup[i] = distribution(generator);

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // main loop:
    for (int i=0; i < n_indices; i += 2) {
        ind_res[i+1] = lookup[ind_res[i]]; // more dense access here, no cache-miss
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "computation took " << elapsed_seconds.count() * 1e9 / n_indices  <<  " ns per element"<< std::endl;
    // printing random numbers to avoid code elimination
    std::cout << ind_res[24] << ind_res[90]; 
    return 0;
}
```

My tests shows tha this code runs much faster.

Comment: OMG. This reduced the time to approximately 0.25 ns per element!

Comment: I don't understand why there are cache misses when I'm using two arrays, not one. Could you explain please?

Comment: Quite surpising =) I faced that behaviour, when I learning about cpu caches and I was realy confused. I think I is related to time diffirences between access to 1L and 2L caches. Since 1L cache can accumulate just 2 or 4 lines, there is a big chance that data can be erised from it. So, when you using two arrays, you need 2 lines of 1L cache, but when you use one array, you need just one. 2 times lower cance for cache-miss.

Comment: it is even more mysterious. I've tried to load/write with a shift: result[i] = lookup[indices[i + shift]] with different shifts. Under some shift I expect not to have conflicts  in L1 cache, but the speed **doesn't depend on shift**. Magic?

Comment: Yea.... my theoy is absolulty wrong =) I used 1000000 shift. No preformance degradation. The dark power of electricity.

Comment: Ok, here what saw in disassembled code. Compiler unrolled the loop, you got 4 times performance boost. Can't paste assebler here, so you just need to beleive me =)

Comment: And again, after the loop was unrolled, there appears 4 sequential reads from the same location and 4 garantied reads from L1 cache without erising.

Comment: I get 0,44ns with OP code and 0,58ns with this code. You should multiply the time by 2, because n_indices is not number of indices now.

Comment: The top CPU frequency is ~3.5 Ghz. It means that there is ~0.28 nanos per cycle. I don't think that there is a chance to read and modify memory/cache faster than cpu 3-4 cycles without vectorising or multithreading. Looks like it's a ceiling for todays serial CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

with -march=native this is what your loops compiles to:

```
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L145:
        movzbl  128(%rsp,%rax), %edx
        movzbl  64(%rsp,%rdx), %edx
        movb    %dl, 1000128(%rsp,%rax)
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpq    $1000000, %rax
        jne     .L145
```

I'm struggling to see how that gets any quicker without parallelisation.

By changing TYPE to int32_t, it gets vectorised:

```
    vpcmpeqd        %ymm2, %ymm2, %ymm2
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L145:
        vmovdqa -8000048(%rbp,%rax), %ymm1
        vmovdqa %ymm2, %ymm3
        vpgatherdd      %ymm3, -8000304(%rbp,%ymm1,4), %ymm0
        vmovdqa %ymm0, -4000048(%rbp,%rax)
        addq    $32, %rax
        cmpq    $4000000, %rax
        jne     .L145
        vzeroupper
```

Might that help?

Comment: Hi, I've benchmarked the code with uint32_t and -march=native, it is slowed down by a factor of 2. But my compiler didn't use vectorization.
`g++ lookup.cpp  -std=gnu++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -march=native -mavx2`, and it is gcc 5.4. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: ok, I got. I was using uint32_t and vectorization didn't work. Now I am using int32_t, code is vectorized (I see vpgatherdd), but application doesn't print anything to output.

Answer (score 2):

At first, there is a bug, distribution(0, 64) produces numbers 0 to 64, 64 can not fit into the array.

You can speed up the lookup 2x by looking up two values a time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#define TYPE uint8_t
#define TYPE2 uint16_t
#define n_lookup 64

void tst() {
    const int n_indices = 1000000;// has to be multiple of 2
    TYPE lookup[n_lookup];
    TYPE indices[n_indices];
    TYPE result[n_indices];
    TYPE2 lookup2[n_lookup * 256];

    // preparations
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n_lookup-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_indices; i++) indices[i] = distribution(generator);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_lookup; i++) lookup[i] = distribution(generator);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_lookup; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_lookup; ++j) {
            lookup2[(i << 8) | j] = (lookup[i] << 8) | lookup[j];
        }
    }

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    TYPE2* indices2 = (TYPE2*)indices;
    TYPE2* result2 = (TYPE2*)result;

    // main loop:
    for (int i = 0; i < n_indices / 2; ++i) {
        *result2++ = lookup2[*indices2++];
    }

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < n_indices; i++) {
        if (result[i] != lookup[indices[i]]) {
            std::cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }
    }

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "computation took " << elapsed_seconds.count() * 1e9 / n_indices << " ns per element" << std::endl;
    // printing random numbers to avoid code elimination
    std::cout << result[12] << result[45];
}

int main() {
    tst();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing bug. Nice approach, in my tests shows ~25-30% speed up.

Comment: My speedup was 2x, obviously the systems are different. You can try moving the main loop to separate function or doing manual loop unroll, but those are just blind shots.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already really fast. However
 (on my system) the execution is about 4.858 % faster when you change

```
const int n_indices = 1000000;
```

to

```
const int n_indices = 1048576; // 2^10
```

This is not much, but it's something.